# Android Compose - Alternative to PlainTooltipBox (deprecated)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

After updating to Compose BOM 2024.02.01, which implements Material 3 v2.0, I realized that I can't use `PlainTooltipBox` anymore. Instead, I see `TooltipBox` and `BasicTooltipBox` (which is implemented by `TooltipBox`).

For both I need to set a `PopupPositionProvider` parameter, but I can't find an example anywhere of how to get and use this.

Can you please explain how to implement the new ToolTip?

The old one was so easy to use , but I know these are Experimental APIs and subject to changes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `PopupPositionProvider` is just a simple interface with a single function that defines where the tooltip should be positioned. You can implement that yourself or you can use the default implementation `TooltipDefaults.rememberPlainTooltipPositionProvider()`:

```
TooltipBox(
    positionProvider = TooltipDefaults.rememberPlainTooltipPositionProvider(),
    tooltip = {
        PlainTooltip {
            Text(/* tooltip content */)
        }
    },
    state = rememberTooltipState(),
) {
    // tooltip anchor
}
```

Comment: This worked! Is there a replacement for Modifier.tooltipAnchor(), or a modifier is not necessary anymore?

Comment: No need for that modifier, it was broken anyways.